# Swift UIInterfaceOrientation for Multiple views

Tags: ios, orientation

I have a navigation controller with multiple views. Most of the views are in portrait, and thus i lock it into portrait view by placing the following code in the Navigation View Controller

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.toRaw()
}
```

This works just fine, and locks all my views in portrait orientation. However, This is 1 view that needs to only be in Landscape. If I use the code above, it locks my Landscape View, into portrait mode, and thus cutting off most of the view.

Can anybody help me out with what to use in the Landscape view controller to lock this particular View in landscape only.

I was using this, but it doesn't work.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.toRaw())
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool{
    // This method is the same for all the three custom ViewController
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small app, the solution I generally use is to have the navigation controller ask the view itself for it's rotation preference:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return visibleViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate()
}
```

Then, in each of your view controllers, you can override shouldAutorotate and and supportedInterfaceOrientations to give each controller the behavior you want.

One additional trick, to ensure that your view can rotate back to it's desired rotation, you can use this to to conditionally allow rotation back to portrait:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return !UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)
}
```